# Разбиение кода на модули

Tags: javascript

Изначально написал "приложение" в весьма хаотичном стиле и сейчас пытаюсь его поперестраивать, поразбивать на разные модули и т.д.

В ходе этого возник следующий момент : один участок кода у меня просто навешивает разные обработчики на всякие объекты dom в документе. Если выносить его в отдельный модуль, то там, как я понимаю, обязательно необходим параметр export (дабы была возможность импортировать это в главный файл). Но в моей ситуации, участок кода ничего не возвращает, а лишь выполняет определённые действия со страницей.

Как здесь правильнее поступить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ уже нашёлся [*click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41179828/es6-import-equivalent-of-require-without-exports) Неосведомленность с более старыми способами импорта - экспорта даёт о себе знать.

```
import "./filename";
```

Несколько других возможных вариантов импорта:

```
import defaultMember from "module-name";  

import * as name from "module-name";  

import { member } from "module-name";  

import { member as alias } from "module-name";  

import { member1 , member2 } from "module-name";  

import { member1 , member2 as alias2 , [...] } from "module-name";  

import defaultMember, { member [ , [...] ] } from "module-name";  

import defaultMember, * as name from "module-name";  

import "module-name";
```

Источник: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import).